# Replacing the largest sprocket in the cassette with a larger one?

Tags: cassette, shifting, sprocket

[image: Whole bicycle]Got this nice old bicycle as a gift from friends, and it has 7 sprockets in the cassette, plus a hub-gear mechanism with three gears (only two of these work though.)

[image: Cassette]

[image: Another view of the cassette]

To come to work I must ride about 7 km, last 2km are uphill, and the last 800m are the steepest. Even with the shifts setup at highest torque, I can manage the entire hill, but only pushing myself to my limits. I would like to have it a little easier.

Would it be a good idea to replace the largest cog in the cassette in this old bicycle with a larger one, so that the toughest uphill parts can become proportionally easier?

Some additional photos:
[Bicycle photo album](https://photos.app.goo.gl/d2ePFBZ66psr2EYGA)

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Without more details, I'm not sure you can get a definite answer.  Could you [edit] in more details, like the sizes of your existing sprockets, the brand/make, capacity of your derailleur...  Photos might help too.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do as soon as I get home and gather all the details accurately. Don´t have the bike with me right now.

Comment: This configuration is most likely to run a screw-on freewheel where it might be difficult to replace a single sprocket. The simplest way would probably be to replace the front chain-ring with a smaller one. Servicing the hub might be a good idea, too.

Comment: Links to photos added

Comment: Hi Raulinbonn. If you [edit] the photos directly into the question, it might get more interest, clicking links is soo 2019

Comment: Ok I had tried but got the impression that only one photo was allowed. After retrying I think I now got how it works, so added the three most important ones to the post.

Comment: The third photo here (bicycle upside-down) shows the older shifting mechanism which as you can see had some damage. It was replaced by a workshop late last Summer, the new one is shown in the second photo.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to find that not only did they make this configuration, but it is still made and is available as a 3 speed IGH (integrated gear hub) and a 9 speed free-hub. I have seen older Altus derailleurs similar to the original in the photo used with 28 tooth 7 speed cassettes. I would feel confident in stating that such a set up would work here. A quick search shows a wide range of 7 speed units are readily available. Looking at the photo of the front crank I don't think a smaller tooth front sprocket would be available. The prospect of installing a 3 speed front crank would be a interesting engineering exercise.

Comment: Thanks! So from what I understand, a full cassette replacement would be needed then, just replacing that biggest cog would be a no go?